# Apache Tiles 2.1.4 runaway leads to StackOverflowError - how to check?

Tags: apache, tiles2, apache-tiles

We have a large web app that makes extensive use of Apache Tiles for page assembly.   Most of the time it works fine but once in a while it throws a StackOverflowError (sample stack trace below).

The fact that these definitions are used thousands of times a day and work 99,999% of the time indicates that this is some weird combination of circumstances.   Does anyone know of a method or tool for going through Apache Tiles definitions and checking them for correctness?  Or is brute force tracing through the definitions the only way?   A lot of people have touched this app over the years and these tiles definitions are pretty ugly.   If there is some way to verify them without manual tracing that would be great...

```
2014-03-18 10:35:24,171 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-275] org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTag - IO Error executing tag: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/search/sitesearch.jsp'.
org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/search/myjsp.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:232)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:669)

    ... snip ...


Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.search.myjsp_jsp._jspService(myjsp_jsp.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor235.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    ... snip ...
```

Sorry for the abbreviated stack trace, but the whole thing is **really** long.